# Conditional statements: finding folders that don't contain a particular file

Tags: files, find, directory, ls

I needed to find all folders, whose names have a digit in them, that don't contain a file ending with .counts.txt. By combining several suggestions I found online, I was able to come up with the following command (for bash), which does what I want.

```
find . maxdepth 1 -type d -name "*[0-9]*" ! -exec sh -c 'ls -1 "{}" | egrep -q "*.counts.txt"' \; -print
```

However, I don't understand some of its features:

1. What does the exclamation mark do here? Does it somehow negate the condition statement that follows?
2. Why is it necessary to open a new shell using `sh` rather than directly piping to `ls`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes the `!` negates the next condition, that is the `-exec sh -c 'ls -1 "{}" | egrep -q "*.counts.txt"' \;`.  As this is an `-exec` condition that is negated we have to remeber that it is true if the command it executes returns with status 0 (and negated the condition is true if the status is not 0).
2. The arguments after `-exec` are not passed to a shell but instead are executed directly so there is no concept of a pipe available.  If you would put a pipe character there the outer shell (which started find itself) would use that and *all* the output from find would go to egrep.

See `man find` for the docs on the `!` and `-exec` args for find.